# Laravel insert category and x products at once

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I have a model Category and a model Products. Now i want to insert 1 category and 10 products coupled to that categroy at once.

How can i achieve that?

```
class Categroy extends Model
{
    public function products() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\Product');
    }
}

class Product extends Model{
    public function categories() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\Category');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is properly documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method). Maybe, you could do something like this?

```
$category = Category::create([
    'name' => 'Properties'
]);

$products = $category->products()->create([
    'name' => 'Apartment',
    'name' => 'Townhouse'
]);
```

Comment: This is a way, but i want to insert 1 array/object with category and products at once, is that also posible